# autentificacion en Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase

En mi App me aurentifico de esta manera y se hace bien.

```
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password ).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Usuario o clave fallido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                toast.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0 );
                LinearLayout toastContentView = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView( MainActivity.this );
                imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.informacion );
                toastContentView.addView( imageView, 0 );
                toast.show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Pero cuando en Realtime Database pongo la regla de usuario, pero no hace nada :

tengo que ponerle la regla publica para que funcione.
¿Lo que quiero es con la autentificacion de arriba autentificarme en Realtime database?

Para mas informacion en could firestore me funciona bien con la regla de usuario.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo estas poniendo la regla de usuario, `request.auth !== null` ? Puedes poner tu security rule para Realtime y Firestore porfa

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}